# The variable loses its value outside the function?

Tags: java, android

I Create a variable called "value_array" Then it put inside it Value of arraylist 
Become like that :   value_array = collection.get(0);
Then I tried to show the result after that Through the Toast function
The result was : Value_1=1
Then I went out of the enqueue function
When I tried to use the Toast function
The result was : Value_1=0
What is the solution to call the same variable ,In the outside of the function so as not to lose its value ,
Look at my code :

```
package com.example.cca.retrofit;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
//https://github.com/metachris/retrofit2-samples
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAXn7VntQvw

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //HttpApiSimple asd;
    private Call<List<Users>> getUsersCall;
    private Call<HttpApi.HttpBinResponse>call;
   // private List<int[]> collection;
    private List<Integer>collection;
    private HttpApi api;
    public int value_array;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // asd = new HttpApiSimple();
        testInstance();
    }

    private void testInstance(){

       api = HttpApi.getInstance();
       value_array = 0;
       api.addHeader("Authorization","MyT23");
        /// Get iteme from index number33333+69

        getUsersCall = api.getService().getAllChatRooms();
        getUsersCall.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<List<Users>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<List<Users>> response, Retrofit retrofit){
                collection = new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++){

                     collection.add(Integer.parseInt(response.body().get(i).id));
                 }

                 value_array = collection.get(1);
                 // Add pramater from another table ;
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Value_1=" + value_array ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                call = api.getService().postWithJson(new HttpApi.LoginData(13,"Rauool",value_array));
                call.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<HttpApi.HttpBinResponse>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<HttpApi.HttpBinResponse> response, retrofit.Retrofit retrofit){
                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.body().message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t){
                //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," " + t.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "lost". The reason why you see no initial value (or 0 as default) is because you make a asynchronous call to get a value for `value_array`. While the call is pending your code still executes regardless and proceeds to make a `Toast` before the result has been received.

There is no fix needed for your case. Simply remove

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Value_2 = " + value_array,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

because it has no value there whatsoever. You have two callback methods `onResponse` and `onFailure`. There you can do whatever you want with the result when it has been received.

Comment: Thanks for you ,Now cannnot call this function                 call = api.getService().postWithJson(new HttpApi.LoginData(12,"uouo",value_array));
// inside enqueue function

Comment: Thanks < i found resolve , but The code has become unorganized Look at the top of the code you have modified